# Magento global messages within newsletter

Tags: magento

Im trying to show the Success Messages of newsletter inside `subscribe.phtml` file which i thought should be very simple but it's not.. 
The code is as below:

```
`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>`
```

and:

```
<?php // Getting Messages from Session
$messages=$messages=Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->getMessages();
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("core/messages")->setMessages($messages)->getGroupedHtml();?>
```

doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions on this?

Cheers,
Avian

Answer (score 3):

have a look at `/app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/controllers/SubscriberController.php`

There is a line like this, where it gets executed:

```
else {
         $session->addSuccess($this->__('Thank you for your subscription.'));
     }
```

line 68 in my file.

This can also be edited in `/app/locale/en_US/Mage_Newsletter.csv` file, and any other language that you wish to support.

Change `"Thank you for your subscription.","Thank you for your subscription."`

to

```
"Thank you for your subscription.","This will be my new message, that I wish to display to users, after subscribing."
```

or to

```
"Thank you for your subscription.",""
```

To display nothing here.

Comment: hey you can change this from locale files :) anything that is called __('this is translatable with inline translation tool or from locale files');

Comment: Thanks shaun, now what if I want to change the position of this message e.g when you give an invalid email id in newsletter signup form it displays a message just underneath texbox which says 'Please enter a valid email address. For example johndoe@domain.com.' On successful signup, I want 'Thank you for your subscription' message to be also displayed on the same position as the error message I just mentioned. Cheers

Comment: have a look at app/design/frontend/base/default/template/newsletter/subscribe.phtml - need to copy it to your own folder to customize. You can add any custom code in there.

Comment: Thanks Shaun this was my original question that Mr Anton did not like and edited it to something completely irrelevant. Anyways in template/page/..column.phtml code that displays global messages <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?> when I use the same call within subscribe.phtml it does not display any messages within the newsletter body! I wonder how can I make it to display the newsletter success message within newsletter body (in subscribe.phtml. My newsletter is within the header of the home page cheers

Comment: Ok, now that is going to get interesting. Will have a look. have you tried: <?php echo $this->getHtml('global_messages') ?>

Comment: By the way, i think you can roll back the question to what it was originally.

Comment: This'<?php echo $this->getHtml('global_messages') ?>'also didn't work. Its really annoying as it looks very simple yet nothing seems to work!!